# React native navigation showing both stacks while condition is used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two stack navigators for my app. Only one should show up, based of the **isLoggedIn** condition. However, both show when **isLoggedIn = true**. But when I set the condition to **false**, it only shows app. I simply dont get it.

```
export default function App() {
 const isLoggedIn = true;
 return (
  <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
          {isLoggedIn === true ? (
          <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthStackNavigator} />
          ) : (
          <Stack.Screen name="App" component={AppBottomTabNavigator} />
          )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
);
}
```

[When isLoggedIn is set to true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BO8M.png)

[When isLoggedIn is set to false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMca1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this.

```
export default function App() {
 const isLoggedIn = true;
 return (
  <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
          {isLoggedIn === true  && <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthStackNavigator} />}
         {isLoggedIn === false && <Stack.Screen name="App" component={AppBottomTabNavigator} />}
      </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
);
}
```

Comment: Found the issue! I was nesting two stack navigators, so in my 'Auth' component, I now return only my screen instead of a navigation. Weird I thought you could just nest navigators.

Comment: Okay so I checked it out but I just forgot to hide the header of a stack navigator. Thanks for the help anyway.